# Delete image from facebook album

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing app which post images to facebook. That's working quite good. But my problem is that i can't find sample that would `delete` selected photo from facebook. I have allready made an `function` that gets the `WallId` and `PhotoID` from facebook.

My problem is that i can't get what should i put in `facebook runner.request` i know that i need to pass `DELETE` and `PhotoId` my function currently is

```
private void delete_fb(){
    AsyncFacebookRunner fruner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,name");
    if(favi.get(indeks).fbid!=0 && WallId != 0){
        fruner.request("me/"+WallId+"/"+favi.get(index).fbid,params ,"DELETE",new Del(),null);
    }
}
```

So if you could explain me what to put in place of `"me/"+WallId+"/"+favi.get(index).fbid` in `fruner.request()` or give me some example code i would be very pleased.

Thank you.

Comment: your function return the postID that you want delete ..??

Comment: @AT_AB Yes. I have checked and they return correct WallId and PhotoId the problem is i cant get what should i do to get that picture deleted from facebook.

Comment: and what's that Del() ??

Comment: @AT_AB Del() is `Request listener` which will tell the if the picture is deleted if that picture is deleted and if that pic is deleted that record will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
fruner.request(YourPostId, params ,"DELETE", new Del(), null);
```